# How do I grab the count when a column equals one or the other value in SQL?

Tags: sql, count

i have a column and the values  can be x y or z, Im having trouble with the syntax.  I want to get add one to the count if the certain value is x or y along with the other parameters.  I believe my "and or" statement is whats giving me wrong data.

Example:

subject

x

y

z

x

I want the count to be 3

```
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM DATA 
                WHERE Assign_To = ('data')
                AND 
                Date_Entered >= ('3/21/2015')
                AND
                Date_Entered <= ('3/22/2015')
                AND
                columnname = ('x')
                OR
                columnname = ('y')";
```

Comment: instead of `columnname = ('x')
                OR
                columnname = ('y')` you could write `columnname IN ('x','y')`

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect Farhegs comment since both OR statements are against the same field an IN clause is the way to go. You will want to group OR statements with Parenthesis when you need to check two different fields though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your OR in parenthesis

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM DATA 
            WHERE Assign_To = ('data')
            AND Date_Entered >= ('3/21/2015')
            AND Date_Entered <= ('3/22/2015')
            AND ( columnname = 'x' OR columnname = 'y' )";
```

Some other suggestions: 
You dont have to wrap everything in parenthesis and use a between statement for the date entered. Between is inclusive. Also since both OR options are against he same field you can use IN instead as mentioned

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM DATA 
            WHERE Assign_To = 'data'
            AND Date_Entered BETWEEN '3/21/2015' AND '3/22/2015'
            AND columnname in ( 'x', 'y' )";
```